# How to scale image according to the pixel size of the screen in python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-canvas

How can I scale the image or any widgets according to the pixel size of the screen using python?

I am using tkinter for making a GUI. Every time I change the pixel size of the screen it changes the place of the widgets on the screen.

Is there any builtin methods in tkinter for it.

Comment: You can fetch the screen size information and scale everything based on that information. But I'm doubtful that you need such a thing if you design your GUI well. Perhaps provide image(s) and [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Tkinter is really good at doing what you ask if you use `pack` or `grid`. If you're using `place`, you are responsible for updating the coordinates yourself.